# jquery nth-child click

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have the following code:

css:

```
nav div:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
nav div:nth-child(2) { background: blue; }
nav div:nth-child(3) { background: yellow; }
```

html:

```
<nav>
 <div>item #1</div>
 <div>item #2</div>
 <div>item #3</div>
</nav>
```

jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.nav div:nth-child').click(function) {
          console.log(this);
      });

  });
```

**edit:** i get now: **uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child**

How to click on the nth-child using jquery and get the item number like CSS do? eg: i click on the second one, jquery will return 2

Comment: you've misspelled nth in your jquery: div:ntd-child

Comment: too much turkey i guess, thanks I updated my answer

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav div').click(function() {
      var index = $(this).index();
      console.log(index);
  });
});
```

index is zero-based

Comment: please use `var`: `var index = $(this).index() + 1;` to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanted to click the Nth of 1 ;ist and do something to the Nth of another list.  You would need to use.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".nav div").on("click", function() {
          var index = $(this).index();
          console.log(index); // Zero Based
          $(".other-nav div:nth-child(" + (parseInt(index) + 1) + ")").show();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The "nav div:nth-child(123)" is a jQuery *selector*, which is only applicable if you wanted to specifically select one. Say, for example, you wanted to handle each click completely independently, as you do with CSS (three rules, three .click()'s).

You want to simply select all nav div's, but then figure out where it is in position. You can do this by subtracting the number of elements by the number of elements after the selected one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('nav div').click(function() {
        var nth_child = $(this).parent().children().length - $(this).nextAll().length;
        console.log(nth_child);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone knows nth-child more than me, but the way I would do it is like this:

```
$('nav div').click(function() {
    var index = $('div').index($(this).parents('div'));
});
```

As a side note, "nav" probably is supposed to be something like .nav or #nav.

Comment: i get an error: missing ( before formal parameters
[Break On This Error] $('nav div').click(function) {

Comment: @Jordan nav is a valid HTML5 element.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just got confused to see `div` inside of `nav`. Normally I would put `a` or `ul`/`li`s, or else you may as well use any other old non-semantic tag.